# WiFi.status(), returns WL_DISCONNECTED (6) when running in AP_MODE

Tags: c++, esp8266, status, arduino-esp8266, access-point

I use an ESP8266 as access point and uses the ESP library 2.4.0. Works perfectly fine, can connect to it etc however when I use the `WiFi.status()` to monitor the 'connection', it allways returns `WL_DISCONNECTED (6)`. Also when I connect to it, this value never change. In station mode, the function seems to working fine.

Is this a bug or do I need to call another function to monitor the status (however, every access point example uses WiFi.status() to monitor)?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A simple connected/disconnected status would have no meaning to an access point which can have multiple concurrently connected clients. Use `WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()` to get the number of currently connected clients. If it's zero, no clients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there another way to figure out WIFI is enabled and active? Because WiFi.status(), it's function name, indicates it can be used to get the status. however, it doesn't seem to be correct. Relying on WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()  is a bit cucumbersome solution, it doesn't represent the actual status.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's a cumbersome solution, or what you're trying to do that isn't served by this function. In AP mode, several clients can be connected simultaneously, so a count is the right indication. The ESP8266 can simultaneously be both AP and station (client) so `WiFi.status()` still has a meaning in that scenario, and if it were somehow used to denote AP status then there'd be nothing left to describe station status. Could you please mark my answer as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: it's a cumbersome solution because a count of users is not the same as to be able to see if the network service is running, operating. Your solution depending on connected users. When there are no users it is not possible to see the network is started. You rely on users and not on the availability of the service. in station mode you can figure out a network is started however in access point mode you can't. For example. A result of zero  connected users is not an error.